# Modal won't work in Vue / Firebase App because '$' is not defined

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex, bootstrap-modal

This is the error it's giving me:

33:7  error  '$' is not defined

This is what's in AddToCart.js. The Modal formatting is in my Product List component.

```
<template>
<div class="add-to-cart">

  <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="addToCart" style="background-color: black; color: whitesmoke; width: 80px; font-size: small">
    Add To Cart
  </button>

</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Add-to-cart",
  props: {
    name: String,
    price: Number,
    ID: String,
  },

  data(){
    return {
      record: {
        recordName: this.name,
        recordPrice: this.price,
        recordID: this.ID,
      },
   }
},

  methods: {
    addToCart() {
      $('#myModal').modal('show')
      this.$store.commit('addToCart', this.record);
    },
  }
};


</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I tried importing $ from bootstrap but that just gave me a new error about $('#myModal').modal('show') not being a function. I just cannot seem to get the modal working.

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you trying to use? Are you aware there's a port specifically tailored to Vue.js ~ https://bootstrap-vue.org/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open your modal using jQuery.

```
 $('#myModal').modal('show')
```

Check if [jQuery library](https://learn.jquery.com/) is loaded. Here are the [jQuery CDNs](https://releases.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You are using bootstrap so you can use

```
this.$bvModal.show("modal-id");
```

to open your modal. (This might depend on your Bootstrap version and might be explicit for bootstrap-vue)

Another way would be

```
this.$refs["modal-ref"].show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend to use JQuery $ sign to access the elements so,
As official document aso suggests that

> Note: It is recommended to use the `this.$bvModal.show()` and `this.$bvModal.hide()` methods (mentioned in the previous section) instead of using $ref methods.

You can Use,
`this.$bvModal.show()` to show and
`this.$bvModal.hide()`hide the modal

Also, this method too applicable

```
this.$refs['my-modal'].show()
this.$refs['my-modal'].hide()
```